# VSCODE COMMIT_EDITMSG without using git

Tags: reactjs, git, visual-studio-code

I have recently copied an `src` folder from one project to a new project file by drag and dropped the folder directly into VSCODE. Once I did that the Staged Changes from the Source Control tab got populated by all the files that I just added.

The problem is that I do not use git. All I did was copy a folder so this means that I cannot commit. If I click on the `commit` button from the Source Control tab a `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file opens and If I tried to click on the checkmark in the up-right corner I get the error that the commit failed due to an empty commit message.

What is this `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file and how can I get rid of the staged changes? And will this have an impact when I `build` the project to upload it on my server?

This is how the file looks

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:

// all the files listed here
```

Comment: did that src/ folder have a "hidden" .git folder in it?

Comment: Apparently yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, Git stores all of its data in a hidden folder called `.git` in the root of the repository.  If you copy a directory that has such a folder in it, then the source is a repository, and typically the destination will also be a repository, since it also includes the `.git` folder.

That means that you do in fact have a Git repository in the destination folder.  When you ask to commit to your repository, Git needs a commit message, and by default it opens a file in your editor called `COMMIT_EDITMSG`.  The intention is that you will edit this message to describe your change, save, and close the window.  Because Git doesn't allow empty messages by default, the commit will fail if you don't edit the message.

If you're using some other version control system, then you should probably delete the `.git` directory from your new project.  That will prevent it from being a Git repository and you'll no longer be prompted to save a commit message by Git.

Comment: You were right. Apparently, there is an invisible folder `.git`. I have one more question. I am doing all the development locally without using `git` or other version control systems. Will deleting this file perish the ability to use `git` in the future. Once I finish I am planning on uploading it to `git hub` and posting it to my server directly from `git`.

Comment: Deleting the `.git` folder will not prevent you from using Git in the future, but it will end up deleting any existing history that you have and make the repository no longer a Git repository until you run `git init` again.